# AVAudioPlayer problems - no issues but doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

To play a button sound when button tapped, I use **AudioToolbox** and **AVFoundation**.
I import these in my .h using

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

Via storyboard, I connected a **UIButton** to a new **IBAction** and then included the following in my .m

```
- (IBAction)playSound11:(id)sender {

//Load an audio file from the bundle
NSString *audioFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"11" ofType:@"mp3"];

//Convert string to NSURL
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFile];

//Initialize an audio player with the mp3 URL
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];

// Start playing
[player play];

}
```

I get no issues and the app does open but there is no sound at all.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your URL perhaps?

This is how I use it

```
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/11.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

Comment: if I understand You correctly I should replace the code with; 
`- (IBAction)playSound11:(id)sender {
     NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/11.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
    [player play];
    }`

But unfortunately, still nothing happens.

Comment: Did you check to see if your 11.mp3 file is in the "Copy Bundle Resources" box of you Project's "Build Phases" tab?

Comment: Yep, it's there, this is crazy! :/

Comment: The next thing I'd do is put an NSLog line inside your playSound11 method to see if its actually going into it. Maybe it's not linked correctly in the IB?

Comment: Nope, not that either. Turns out it is a problem with ARC, I'll look into that.